# What is the probability of certain numbers to be included in a drawn sample?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations, factorial

Say I have 10 ping pong balls, these balls are labeled 1 through 10. I pick 4 with replacement. What are the chances that the 4 balls I picked are the numbers 3, 5, 7, and 9?

I have calculated the possibilities of choosing 4 from these 10, I believe there are 10,000 possibilities. I did this by 10^4.
I also know that each number has 1/10 chance of getting chosen with replacement.

But I am not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You should update your post (Click "Edit" above") to tell about your efforts so far. As it looks now, you may attract some negative votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many ways are there to pick 4 balls with replacement? It may be useful to consider combinations and permutations here.

Now, how many ways are there to pick 4 balls numbered 3, 5, 7, 9?

Once you have these, apply the definition of probability to get your desired result.

Comment: So I found that there are 10,000 different possibilities. But only 24 combinations of 3,5,7,9. Would that mean there's a .24% chance? Did I do this correctly?

Comment: @d2nf9s8nbhy Yes, that's it exactly.  To expand your intuition, the possible distribution of numbers chosen is [A] 4 [B] 3-1 [C] 2-1-1 [D] 2-2 [E] 1-1-1-1.  The enumeration of each distribution is [A] $[10]$. [B] $[(10 \times 9) \times 4]$. [C] $[\binom{10}{2} \times 8 \times (4 \times 3)]$. [D] $[\binom{10}{2} \times \binom{4}{2}]$. [E] $[\binom{10}{4} \times 4!]$.  You will notice that the sum of the enumerations of [A] + [B] + [C] + [D] + [E] $~= 10^4$.

Comment: Given that the balls are chosen with replacement, it is not useful to consider combinations or permutations.  Counting the number of elements in the sample space  is a straightforward application of the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).